# Horde RPC interface

Tags: rpc, horde

I've been trying to read and write on calendars from Horde (Kronolith) via RPC for some time now.

I'm using the following example: http://wiki.horde.org/WSDLHowTo

The problem is, that I don't get any response from the server (I've tried 2 completely different servers, where I have an account). I always get a blank answer no matter which method I choose (eg. `horde_listAPIs` or `calendar_list`, which are both listed in the `rpc.php?wsdl` file). It looks like I can connect successfully to both (if I give wrong username and/or password, I get a login error). I couldn't connect to the demo server on the [Horde homepage](http://demo.horde.org/)

Does anyone have a working example for a RPC Horde connection?

Comment: Some time ago I finished the project. Here is the working synchronizer between Horde and Google Calendar: http://sourceforge.net/projects/kron2gcalsync/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use gmail as a "backend" in horde's kronolith?

I see you already fixed it, but just for users browsing by:

If you need a working example of Horde RPC usage, see 
http://www.ralf-lang.de/2012/02/18/distributed-applications-with-horde-4/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While you are right in general, it's probably a copyright violation to copy/paste the complete example.